# When i add a hook modifier to a 2d filled bezier circle the fill dissapears

Tags: bezier-curves

When i add a hook modifier to a 2d filled bezier circle the fill dissapears. Im trying to use it to anaimate a crude mouth. Help please!

Comment: I think you might have to use a mesh, instead